# An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization"

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, solid-state-drive

I'm alternating between a Mac mini or MBP.

I created a few spring projects and saved the workspace on my external drive SSD T5. Whenever launching SpringToolSuite from the SSD on either computer, I get the following error.

An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization".
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException

If I move the workspace to my local disk on the Mac mini or MBP, I don't experience this error.

Any suggestions on how I can avoid this error? It doesn't stop me from working but is annoying to see each time I launch STS.

Here is a [link to the stack trace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17g7BLjCsdIiaAgsOZD-wU6oQ3RGsFaZ6/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Does the .log in the .metadata have a full stack trace? Eclipse [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?format=advanced) has a number of reports for this exception but it is not clear if this matches any of them.

Comment: @greg-449 I just added the link to it at the end of the post. Does that help?

Comment: maybe something to discuss here? https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/169

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this java bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8205404

Basically, seems to depend on the formatting for the external drive.